# How to interrupt a ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a `ScheduledExecutorService` that I am using to run a method `updateIndex()` every one minute. However, if changes to resources are made during the one minute between the last refresh and the next refresh, I would like to have `updateIndex()` called immediately, and then have the executor service resume it's normal schedule; i.e. next update will take place in one minute. However, I haven't seen anything in the documentation to suggest there is the capability to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void updateIndex() {
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            //Do your logic here
        };
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
```

According to JavaDocs

```
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period; that is executions will commence after initialDelay then initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on. If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor. If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

Comment: So it's not possible to "interrupt" the executor withing the waiting period in between executions of the Runnable command?

Comment: You can interrupt the runnable using scheduledExecuter

Comment: ScheduledFuture<?> scheduler = scheduledExecutor
    .schedule(() -> yourlogicmethod();
  DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
  currentTime = currentTime.plus(scheduler.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

Answer (score 1):

`scheduleAtFixedRate()` returns a [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) which is a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which has the `cancel` method you're looking for.