# how to print one character at a time on one line using a METHOD

Tags: java, methods

So I'm well aware that I can delay lines using the following code

```
long time=100L;
listLine[1] = "You are on a war-torn Plateau";

   for ( int i= 0; i < listLine[1].length(); i++) { 
          // for loop delays individual String characters

        System.out.print(listLine[1].charAt(i));
        Thread.sleep(time); //time is in milliseconds
    }
        System.out.println(""); // this is the space in between lines
```

;
However using this repeatedly in code is redundant and makes it hard to read my code. Is there a way to implement a function/method so that the code instead looks akin to the following.

```
public static void delay() {
     // your solution to my problem goes here

System.out.print(listLine[0].delay();
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: i don´t really get what you want to be honest. You want a nested loop?

Comment: For delay, you may use scheduler executer service feature of Java 8, you can find the link here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439694/how-to-interrupt-a-scheduledexecutorservice/45439902#45439902

Comment: I don't see what's redundant in the original code. It's the second snippet that's incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a delayed typing effect based on the first code snippet. The code there should be fine, all you need to do is migrate that code into a method so you can repeatedly create that delayed effect.

```
public void delay(String s, long delay) {
    for ( int i= 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
          // for loop delays individual String characters

        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        Thread.sleep(delay); //time is in milliseconds
    }
    System.out.println(""); // this is the space in between lines
}
```

Followed by a method call such as

```
delay("You are on a war-torn Plateau", 100L);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert a string to character array and then print this using code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String sample = "Hello World";
    printCharactersWithDelays(sample, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 400);
}

public static void printCharactersWithDelays(String sample, TimeUnit unit, long delay){
    List<Character> chars = sample.chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
    chars.forEach(character -> {
        System.out.println(character);
        try {
            unit.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to collect into list - you can simply print from stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer :

```
 package stack;

    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class Scheduling {

      String string = "You are on a war-torn Plateau";
      Timer timer;
      int index = 0;

      public Scheduling() {
        timer = new Timer();
        //this method schedule the task repeatedly with delay of 1sec until the timer is not cancel
        timer.schedule(new Delay(), 0, 1000);
      }

      public class Delay extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          if (index == string.length()) {
            timer.cancel();
          } else {
            System.out.println(string.charAt(index));
            index++;
          }
        }
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scheduling();
      }
    }
```

In above answer I use `java.util.Timer` class for timing and `TimerTask` class is used to do task which we want to do with delay.

Comment: there is no answer for wrong question (philosophic)